# Angular One controller fetches data and loads into other controller

Tags: angularjs

I have such application:

```
---------------
NAVBAR [SEARCH] (< navCtrl)
---------------
TR NG GRID      (< gridCtrl)
```

I want to trigger a function if something is typed into the search bar residing at the navbar that loads `myData` object (from my API) into the `gridCtrl`.

How to achieve such?

Comment: You can activate the data fetching based on the `navbar` search text. The data fetching can be achieved using a service and it will be updated a data model. The grid control can be programmed to listen on the data model (at the service level) changes (data received) and display them at the grid level. In another apporach, you would use a broadcast message at the `$rootScope` level once the data received. The grid controller will listen to this message and display the data. However, this approach is not recommended as broadcast messages are discouraged for data updating event transmission.

Comment: Thanks mate, I will report back when having implemented the first approach.

Comment: If you need some insights I can provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have added some sample implementation as an answer as explained above.

```
.factory('SearchService', function($http, SearchedDataCache) {
    var searchService = {};
    var requestURl = '';

    searchService.search = function(searchquery) {
        // Calling the back-end to do the actual search
        requestURl = '/search_url';
        return $http.post(requestURl, searchquery)
            .then(function(res) {
                // Search success, process data
                SearchedDataCache.setSearchResults(res.data);

                // Return the promise
                return res.data;
            }, function(res) {
                // Operation Failed
                console.log('<SearchService> Search failed ' + res.data);
                return res.data;
            }
        );
    };

    return searchService;
})


.service('SearchedDataCache', function($rootScope) {
    var searchResults   = [];       // Holds the current search results

    // Assign search results
    this.setSearchResults = function(searchResponse) {
        $.each(searchResponse, function(index, element) {
            searchResults.push(element);
        });
        console.log('<SearchedDataCache.results> # of search results ' + searchResults.length);

        // This can be used if we use broadcast message event based data update
        $rootScope.$broadcast('search-store-updated');
    };

    this.getSearchResults = function() {
        return searchResults;
    };

    return this;
})

.controller('SearchGridController', [ '$scope', 'SearchedDataCache',
    // For broadcast message event based implementation
    function($scope, SearchedDataCache) {
        $scope.$on('search-store-updated', function () {
            $scope.results = SearchedDataCache.getSearchResults();

            // Use the results to display
        });
    }

    // Data model reference based implementation
    $scope.results = SearchedDataCache.getSearchResults();
    $scope.$watch('results', function() {
        // Use the results to display
    });

])
```